# Cannot login into Salesforce with Java using Proxy Server

Tags: java, salesforce

I wrote Java code to login to Salesforce and ran this code on a firewalled server. For this, I have to specify the proxy url and proxy port before connecting to Salesforce due to the firewall. However, I'm getting an unknownhostexception error for the proxy url. If I try to login via curl with the proxy settings, I am able to connect. How come there is a problem connecting using Java then? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was caused by JVM configs. We have to configure JVM to use the proxy settings as follows:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", crmProxyURL);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", crmProxyPort);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your HTTP library the System settings might not be enough or not needed. In the [Salesforce context](https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector) it is quite possible that one would try using the [Jetty HTTP Client](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.7.v20170914/http-client-proxy.html). In this case the System properties are ignored and proxy needs to be handled by the Jetty client:

```
ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = httpClient.getProxyConfiguration();
HttpProxy proxy = new HttpProxy("proxyHost", proxyPort);
proxyConfig.getProxies().add(proxy);
```

The [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), another popular choice, also uses its own little mechanism:

```
 HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxyHost", proxyPort, "https");
 RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet(someURL);
 request.setConfig(config);
```

Interesting here: one can specify to use http or https as the proxy protocol.

In general I found using one of the http client much easier that the JDK low level functions.